# boost python enable_pickling expectation

Tags: python, c++, boost, pickle

Hi I am using python to initiate a cpp class which use boost python lib to convert into python usable. at the same time, i have a requirement to pickle the python classes that use the python enabled cpp class.

So what i did is to add enable_picking() to an example class definition like this:

```
class_<pform::base::Price>("Price", init<double>())
      .def(self == self)
      .def(self_ns::str(self_ns::self))  // __str__
      .def("get_value", &pform::base::Price::get_value)
```

it make the class pickleable. However i get this error when unpickle it.

```
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    Price.__init__(Price)
did not match C++ signature:
    __init__(_object*, double)
```

So what is missing here?

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but I found the relevant boost documentation for this:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/topics/pickle_support.html

> **The Pickle Interface**
>
> At the user level, the Boost.Python pickle
>   interface involves three special methods:
>
> - `__getinitargs__` When an instance of a Boost.Python extension class is pickled, the pickler tests if the instance has a `__getinitargs__`
>     method. This method must return a Python tuple (it is most convenient
>     to use a `boost::python::tuple`). When the instance is restored by the
>     unpickler, the contents of this tuple are used as the arguments for
>     the class constructor. If `__getinitargs__` is not defined, pickle.load
>     will call the constructor (`__init__`) without arguments; i.e., the
>     object must be default-constructible.
> - `__getstate__` When an instance of a Boost.Python extension class is pickled, the pickler tests if the instance has a `__getstate__` method.
>     This method should return a Python object representing the state of
>     the instance.
> - `__setstate__` When an instance of a Boost.Python extension class is restored by the unpickler (pickle.load), it is first constructed using
>     the result of `__getinitargs__` as arguments (see above). Subsequently
>     the unpickler tests if the new instance has a `__setstate__` method. If
>     so, this method is called with the result of `__getstate__` (a Python
>     object) as the argument.
>
> The three special methods described above may
>   be `.def()`'ed individually by the user. However, Boost.Python provides
>   an easy to use high-level interface via the
>   `boost::python::pickle_suite` class that also enforces consistency:
>   `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` must be defined as pairs. Use of this interface is demonstrated by the following examples.

In your particular example the class is not default constructible as it needs a `double` argument (which I assume is the "value"). To wrap it for Python you would also need to define:

```
.def("__getinitargs__", +[](pform::base::Price const& self){
  return boost::python::make_tuple(self.get_value());
})
```

Now Boost Python will initialize your class using "value"; instead of calling the default constructor (`pform::base::Price()`).